English version of Kitsur Shulchan Aruch of Yalkut Yosef
I wonder if this book can be found in English, better if online for free. Or if there is a similar book like this that you can suggest me, again better if online for free. Ty


BH
By the way on links bellow it’s really good to use ChatGPT for word by word translation, supper good stuff for learning. Good Starting prompts are “Translate or can you translate this and this etc word by word?” And if you paste the whole paragraph or some of the halachot it actually gives you good translation word by word obviously good to go together with chavruta tho when possible however for just translation its supper good.

Yalkut Yosef with English Translation - Set - Saka Edition [18 volumes]
https://judaicaspot.com/products/yalkut-yosef-17-vol-set
Gil Student describes a free version here: https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/02/weekly-freebies-kitzur-yalkut-yosef/

The Kitzur Shulchan Arukh (link) by R. Shlomo Ganzfried is a classic
condensation of practical Jewish law as it was practiced in mid-18th
century greater Hungary. It has been adapted a few times, including R.
Gersion Appel’s Concise Code of Jewish Law.
R. Yitzchak Yosef’s version based on the rulings of his father, R. Ovadiah Yosef, is titled Kitzur Shulchan Arukh Yalkut Yosef and is
available (without footnotes) online for free: [Inactive
link]


Just to point out to anyone that it's not obvious to- the Saka Edition is not Kitsur
